# asp.net mvc3 - Controller method returns View(viewName, string) but weirdness ensues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

has anyone seen this issue? I'm an ASP.NET MVC newbie. I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 site that uses .aspx and .ascx views. Throughout the site, I use return View() or return View(viewName) in my controller methods, which directs to the appropriate aspx/ascx view. However, in my stock AccountController (modified to use DotNetOpenAuth), I take the same approach, but the MVC framework doesn't seek out aspx or ascx views. Instead, it's searching the path for .cshtml or .vbhtml views (Razor engine I'm assuming). Why woulnd't it just seek out aspx and ascx views like the rest of my site? Controller method follows:

```
public ActionResult Authenticate()
{
    var response = openid.GetResponse();
    var statusMessage = "";
    if (response == null)
    {
        Identifier id;
        //make sure your users openid_identifier is valid.
        if (Identifier.TryParse(Request.Form["openid_identifier"], out id))
        {
            try
            {
                //request openid_identifier
                return openid.CreateRequest(Request.Form["openid_identifier"])
                   .RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
            }
            catch (ProtocolException ex)
            {
                statusMessage = ex.Message;
                return View("LogOn", statusMessage);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            statusMessage = "Invalid identifier";
            return View("LogOn", statusMessage);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //check the response status
        switch (response.Status)
        {
            //success status
            case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                Session["FriendlyIdentifier"] = response.FriendlyIdentifierForDisplay;
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(response.ClaimedIdentifier, false);

                //TODO: response.ClaimedIdentifier, to login or create new account 

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
                statusMessage = "Canceled at provider";
                return View("LogOn", statusMessage);

            case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
                statusMessage = response.Exception.Message;
                return View("LogOn", statusMessage);
        }
    }
    return View("LogOn");
}
```

Error detail follows:

> The view 'LogOn' or its master was not
>   found or no view engine supports the
>   searched locations. The following
>   locations were searched:
>   ~/Views/Account/Canceled at
>   provider.master
>   ~/Views/Shared/Canceled at
>   provider.master
>   ~/Views/Account/LogOn.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Account/LogOn.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/LogOn.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/LogOn.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Account/Canceled at
>   provider.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Account/Canceled at
>   provider.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Canceled at
>   provider.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Canceled at
>   provider.vbhtml
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   view 'LogOn' or its master was not
>   found or no view engine supports the
>   searched locations. The following
>   locations were searched:
>   ~/Views/Account/Canceled at
>   provider.master
>   ~/Views/Shared/Canceled at
>   provider.master
>   ~/Views/Account/LogOn.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Account/LogOn.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/LogOn.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/LogOn.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Account/Canceled at
>   provider.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Account/Canceled at
>   provider.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Canceled at
>   provider.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Canceled at
>   provider.vbhtml
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The view
>   'LogOn' or its master was not found or
>   no view engine supports the searched
>   locations. The following locations
>   were searched:
>   ~/Views/Account/Canceled at
>   provider.master
>   ~/Views/Shared/Canceled at
>   provider.master
>   ~/Views/Account/LogOn.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Account/LogOn.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/LogOn.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/LogOn.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Account/Canceled at
>   provider.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Account/Canceled at
>   provider.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Canceled at
>   provider.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Canceled at
>   provider.vbhtml]
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext
>   context) +315050
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext
>   context) +129
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult
>   actionResult) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1c.b*_19()
>   +23    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation) +260 
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()
>   +19    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters,
>   ActionResult actionResult) +177
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)
>   +343    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
>   +116    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +97
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassb.b*_5()
>   +37    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0()
>   +21    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) +12    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +62    System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClasse.b_*d()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b*_0(Action
>   f) +7
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action
>   action) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +8841105    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +184

Thanks
Shan

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The key is in the first line of your exception:

```
The view 'LogOn' or its master was not found or no view engine supports 
the searched locations. The following locations were searched: 
~/Views/Account/Canceled at provider.master
```

If you pass two strings to View(), the first one is the view name and the second one is the name of the master view or template to use.  If you want to pass statusMessage as the model for your view you can cast it to object which will force calling the overridden [View() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view.aspx) where you pass a model:

```
return View("LogOn", (object)statusMessage);
```

You are apparently getting the "Cancelled at provider" message and passing that as the master page name to use.  If the "Logon.aspx" view used a master page and you had a master page "Canceled at provider.master" in your Shared view folder for instance, this would load the "LogOn.aspx" view and force it to use the "Canceled at provider.master" master page even if it was setup to use a different master page by default:

```
string statusMessage = "Canceled at provider";
return View("LogOn", statusMessage);
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, I'll give that a try later my evening. Any thought regarding the ASP.NET MVC message "The view 'LogOn' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations."?  I totally overlooked that ASP.NET MVC 3 was looking for "Canceled at provider", and was stuck more on the fact that it _was_ searching for a LogOn.cshtml (see the search paths in the message, you'll find ~/Views/Account/LogOn.cshtml for instance), and not for LogOn.aspx or LogOn.ascx.

Comment: I'm not sure of the logic, but I think it is because it halts when it cannot find the master page.  If you put the master page there it does indeed find LogOn.aspx and use the specified  master.